# How can i get the logs of terminated instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My EC2 ubuntu instance( id: xxx) got terminated due to EC2 instance status checks failure and launched itself as an new instance (yyy). I wanted to see know the reason behind the termination here. I attempted to have a look `CloudTrail -> Event History -> Event Name (Lookup Attributes) -> TerminateInstances`. But that didn't help me find a reason for this termination. I also tried using CLI `aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id xxx`, but what I got is empty array

`{ "Reservations": [] }`

Any help in finding a way to get the logs would be great.

Comment: "didn't help me find a reason for this termination"  what do you expect to find? What kind of reason?

Comment: @Marcin  For ex: "Your instance will be terminated because of resource overload or volume limit exceeded etc". This way I can prevent it from happening again. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting-launch.html#troubleshooting-launch-internal

Comment: Terminated instance stay for short while only in your account. If you waited too long, you can't get its info back.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. So what's done is done and I can't find the reason why? :(